# Python Interpreter on Android

Tags: android, python

So I want to practice python on my Android. Is there a way I can get the interpreter or an interpreter emulator on my device?

Comment: Well, there's always https://www.pythonanywhere.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also [Python for Android](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/) (Py4A), which is intended to work with SL4A.  The documentation for Py4A is not as extensive as SL4A, but there are a few examples for Py4A available [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/wiki/Examples).

In addition, there's [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home), a crossplatform Python-based development framework for Android, PC, Linux, and iOS.  I've played around with Kivy a little bit in the past, and while it's very powerful, it's documentation has been lacking, and the code is difficult to decipher.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `termux` app, [link to homepage](https://termux.com/), which is available in the [google market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en) and requires no root. It is a terminal emulator with a full Linux environment and via `apt install python` you can install `python`. `apt list` gives you a list of all available packages.

Comment: This works, but unless you want to use Vim with an Android keyboard, it's not ideal. The solution is to use a separate app to edit your code, but that's still a lot of work. Unfortunately, there aren't many good options that I've found

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Scripting Layer 4 Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) (sl4a).

There are a number of good Python examples [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/Tutorials).

Answer (score 1):

Download PyDroid 3 from Playstore and if you like it buy the pro version. It costs around 2$ but you have all you need to do Python 3 programming