# How to add matplotlib graph on android app

Tags: android, python, database, matplotlib, kivy

I want to know how to add matplotlib graph on an Android app that is, a program using python and kivy. I want my app to make a data visualization graph using the data that it will collect from the phone. I am an amateur programmer if you could make the explanation simple please. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using python and matplotlib on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353203/using-python-and-matplotlib-on-android)

Comment: You didn't answer my question?