# Running Odoo (OpenERP) Server on Android

Tags: android, python, odoo, odoo-mobile

I'm developing Odoo (formerly OpenERP) modules on Ubuntu right now. Because of my mobility, I decide to use Android devices to continue my works anywhere so I won't depend on my PC. Is it possible to run Odoo server on Android? As you know developing Odoo modules needs a couple of tests.

Thank you.

Comment: As I know that it's not possible to do so at the moment. If it's possible, the development process will not be smooth as in PC OS like Ubuntu or Windows. To run the odoo server, lots of libraries have to be installed (I havent checked if they fully support Android or not). In addition, when developing odoo, you have to run database server like Postgres together with odoo server and this is not a good idea. Hope this help

Comment: You can use an online development service, so that you can work in any device as long as it has a modern browser. If you want a reference, I was successful at installing and developing for Odoo using [Nitrous](https://www.nitrous.io/).

Comment: r u try the odoo-mobile framework?

Comment: @RanjithKumar , Nope. I try run odoo server framework.

Comment: I did work on a odoo application on android platform and its live now working fine.

Comment: How can you possibly write codes on a smartphone/tablet ? It's not just about typing. How would you do if you figure out that you need a certain Python package ? On a computer you would do `pip install package`. How would you do that on a mobile device ? Buy a laptop.

Comment: Consider looking at [OdooJsonRpcClient ](github.com/kasim1011/OdooJsonRpcClient) for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You have to identify the components/programs/libraries of an Odoo server and install them yourself.

**First** of all Odoo uses PostgreSQL as its DBMS. I do not think that PostgreSQL has been ported to Android. But I do know that it is written in C and you can compile it with android NDK tool-chain. Thing is that you have to see which libraries (dependencies) does postgres have.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pgandroid/STg8xObGFlo

**Second** Odoo business logic is written in Python. You therefore need to install a Python interpreter to your Android device. A quick search gave this: 
[Python Interpreter on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793158/python-interpreter-on-android)

**Third** you have to identify which Python modules does Odoo use beside its own (ie. libraries that are managed and installed by PyPA on a desktop machine). Some of which are these:
http://pastebin.com/2cju5BRA

These three are the gist, but many other issues could arise later on even if you do manage to get all the libraries (they are too many, trust me).

Odoo is a resource intensive kind of application (reads/writes on the database for almost every action possible.

**Conclusion**: For educational purposes I would do it. So that I can learn from it. But I believe that the time you will save by having your server on the android device will definitely outweigh the time you will waste porting the whole thing to android.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to run Odoo server on Android?

***Answer*** - possible with help of Odoo-Mobile framework.

### Odoo-Mobile/Framework

Odoo Mobile framework is an open source mobile application development framework with Odoo integration. With the help of this mobile framework we can rapidly develop almost all Odoo supported application as faster as we can develop in Odoo Framework.
This framework contains its own ORM to handle mobile’s local database. So you do not have to worry about data coming from Odoo Server. It has pre-developed services and providers to make your application data synchronized with Odoo.

[image]

**Odoo-Mobile Framework Repository**

https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework

**Official Guide for Implementation**

http://mobile.odoo.co.in/v2/getting-started/index.html